# Books on relationship between language and society / environment

Tags: reference-request

Can you recommend some books on the connection between language features and (historical) features of the society or circumstances?

Obvious examples: A homogeneous language without dialects would go with a centralized state and open geography. A language with a single form of address would go with a rather egalitarian society.

Comment: Your question presupposes that: 1) there is a connection between the quality of a society and the quality of its language, and 2) this connection is also non-arbitrary. These assumptions could fall under the rubric of "The Sapir-Whorf" hypothesis, or Neo-Whorfianism, which are both rather controversial and disfavored by modern linguists/psychologists.

Comment: I don't think that the examples I mentioned have anything to do with the Sapir-Whorf thesis, and the general question might well have as answer a book that explains why there is no influence from language on society.

Comment: This question also presupposes that the language came before the 'society', if 'society' is taken to mean the organizational structure or social norms of a group of people. And it's very hard to go far back enough to know whether certain linguistic features arose before or after certain features of a society, unless you're lucky enough to have a lot of written records. Regardless, this question certainly is closely related to the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis, even if you're just trying to find evidence that the hypothesis is unfounded.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen many books on this topic over the years in Galicia, perhaps due to its strong diglossic history and present. Off the top of my head, I can recall [*Diglossia and Power: Language Policies and Practice in the 19th Century Habsburg Empire* by Rosita Rindler Schjerve](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110176548).

Comment: Language policy and its effect on society is not the same thing as the actual linguistic features of a language, and their potential influence on a society.

Comment: @FloatingTone: Indeed. The interesting thing is, some language policies have been put into practice because of the linguistic characteristics of the language, and their expected effects on society. Point in case, the *pronome de solidariedade* ("solidarity pronoun") in Galician (a linguistic property) and the ban of the Galician language in North-West Spain (a policy) in order to obtain a more submissive society.